# Three.js edit PlaneGeometry

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have a PlaneGeometry for T-shirt with texture and a image for the design like this [image]
[image]

My ideal is add a PlaneGeometry with texture for the design and put it on the T-shirt PlaneGeometry. This's my best result [image]

Here is my code:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 300 / 300, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvasRef.current,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(300, 300);
renderer.setClearColor("#eee");

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load(
  "/t-shirt data url/",
  function (texture) {
    texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(700, 700);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while loading the texture:", error);
  }
);

const designTextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
designTextureLoader.load(
  "/design data url/",
  function (texture) {
    texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(340, 400);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    mesh.position.z = 1;
    mesh.scale.x = 0.65;
    mesh.scale.y = 0.65;
  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred while loading the texture:", error);
  }
);

const render = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
render();
```

I want the design PlaneGeometry look more realistic on the T-shirt, and also want to remove the black background at the design PlaneGeometry but don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't specific enough for me. It's an open-ended design problem that omits a lot of details, and when those are provided, would fit a commercial job more than a SO question. Please elaborate on what you've tried, what approaches have you thought of and what you've evaluated so far, present relevant code samples and highlight the issues you've encountered.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, I just updated it, hope it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Use an application like [Adobe Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) to trace around the part of the t-shirt you want to allow designs to be applied to.

Pass the SVG to [SVGLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/SVGLoader):

```js
const loader = new SVGLoader();

loader.load("/src/t-shirt-mask.svg", ({ paths }) => {
  const shapes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    const path = paths[i];
    const subShapes = path.toShapes();
    shapes.push(...subShapes);
  }
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "crimson",
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    const shape = shapes[i];
    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    const boundingBox = geometry.boundingBox;
    const center = boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    geometry.translate(-center.x, -center.y, -center.z);
    const s = 1 / 200;
    mesh.scale.set(s, -s, s);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
});
```

Note the SVG is flipped on the `y` axis, centred, and scaled down.

Now you can add a [CanvasTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture) to the shape mesh to apply textures to the 2D canvas.

Here's the full code for creating geometry from an SVG file:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.0/build/three.module.js";
      import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
      import { SVGLoader } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js";

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera.position.z = 2;

      const loader = new SVGLoader();

      loader.load("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/enijar/7831a277b60167a46ce042025bdc07f1/raw/1201803cbe17563a25e3eff78d561caa25dee06a/t-shirt-mask.svg", ({ paths }) => {
        const shapes = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          const path = paths[i];
          const subShapes = path.toShapes();
          shapes.push(...subShapes);
        }
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: "crimson",
          side: THREE.DoubleSide
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
          const shape = shapes[i];
          const geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
          const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
          geometry.computeBoundingBox();
          const boundingBox = geometry.boundingBox;
          const center = boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
          geometry.translate(-center.x, -center.y, -center.z);
          const s = 1 / 200;
          mesh.scale.set(s, -s, s);
          scene.add(mesh);
        }
      });

      (function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        controls.update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: generate t-shirt shape is good, but that not what I really mean, I want the design shape with texture look more realistic on the T-shirt. Maybe because the bad question info I ask, I updated the question